# How to correctly shut down a JUnit-Runner?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit-runner

I made my own JUnit-Runner by implementing `org.junit.runner.Runner`, so that I can run my UnitTests with them using the `@RunWith`-Annotation.

It lookes somewhat like this:

```
public class MyRunner extends Runner {

    private Context myContext;
    myContext.init();
    private final BlockJUnit4ClassRunner runner;

    public MyRunner(final Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        myContext = new Context();

        runner = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final RunNotifier notifier) {
        runner.run(notifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return runner.getDescription();
    }

    public void filter(final Filter filter) throws NoTestsRemainException {
        runner.filter(filter);
    }
}
```

To clean up resources, I have to shut down `MyContext` by calling `MyContext.close()`. Where should I invoke this so that my resources are cleand up after the tests have run?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Where should I invoke this so that my resources are cleand up after
>   the tests have run ?

**UPDATED MY ANSWER, you can use `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener` as shown below:**

**(1) Create your own RunListener class:**

```
public class MyRunnerListener extends RunListener {
    private Context context;

    public MyRunnerListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

     void   testRunFinished(Result result)  {
          context.close();
     }
}
```

**(2) Use the MyRunnerListener inside MyRunner :**

```
public class MyRunner extends Runner {

    private Context myContext;
    MyRunnerListener runnerListener;
    private final BlockJUnit4ClassRunner runner;

    public MyRunner(final Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        myContext = new Context();
        myContext.init();
        runnerListener = new MyRunnerListener(myContext);

        runner = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.addListener(runnerListener);
        runner.run(notifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return runner.getDescription();
    }

    public void filter(final Filter filter) throws NoTestsRemainException {
        runner.filter(filter);
    }
}
```

**P.S.: If you don't want to use the `Runner`, then you can follow the answer from Markus (which uses `TestRule`, NOT `TestRunner`).**

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as this applies to classes under test, but not the runner.

Comment: Updated the answer, look at it

Comment: That won't work because a runner might be used by multiple test classes.

Comment: I have tested this and as there will be multiple testrunner objects (one for each Test Class) and each will close their context

Comment: The solution also contradicts the idea of the Runner. The class under test shouldn't be required to modify the state of the runner.

Comment: I accept with this point, but your first point states that it does not work.. which is not correct ? do you agree ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128478/discussion-between-javaguy-and-bob).

Comment: Using the RunListener makes sense. The code you posted doesn't work, though. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achive but have you already had a look at **[JUnit's `Rule`s](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules)**?

```
public class MyContextRule extends ExternalResource {

    private final Context myContext;

    public MyContextRule()  {
        myContext = new Context();
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        myContext.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        myContext.close();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static MyContextRule contextRule = new MyContextRule(); 

    //...
}
```

JUnit `Rule`s advantage over `Runner`s is that you can have multiple of them, while you only can have one runner.

So, your custom `Rule` could be used with any runner that may be introduced by a random testframework that you may come across in the future...